# Extjs How to stop form tooltip from removing focus from a form textfield

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, tooltip

I do not know if this happens to you but when I create a form and have a bunch of textfields inside with some type of validation (let's say maxLength) then whenever I violate this and the tooltip appears, for some reason it removes the focus from the textfield. This is really annoying because since you have gone over the max length the next step is to press "backspace" in order to delete some characters but since there is no focus in the textfield backspace executes "Back" of the browser and everything is lost. I tried to search for some related configs and stuff but I haven't found anything yet and there's nothing on the internet. It looks like this:

[image: Example image right after losing focus]

Comment: Could you post your textield configs? I fiddled one but i cant reproduce what you are saying, tooltip appears and focus is still on the textfield. Also, what version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you are using ExtJS 5.0.2.xxx, so if you don't have a problem using nightly builds, the latest ones (from Oct 14th 2014 on) fix this bug.

Here is a report of this bug being found and fixed: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?293325

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ExtJS 5.0.1? I think it's a bug, I've seen the same behaviour.

As a temporary solution you can add the following to your textfield to avoid the tooltip interfering with the field focus:

```
msgTarget:'side' // or 'under'
```

While this might not be preferable as to your design guide lines - it might be better than to wait for Sencha to fix it.

Comment: Hi Tomgranerod, I just saw your answer but it seems that msgTarget : 'side', would still remove the focus from the field. msgTarger: 'under' seems to solve the problem but I guess it would break the layout of a Password form field :(

Comment: As a matter of fact I'm using ExtJS 5.0.2.XXXX weird build since it fixed a previous bug I had. If it is indeed a bug then at least I'd like to be able to remove the tooltip or move it to the side or something. I'll try your solution tomorrow when I get to work and see if it works.